# Failed to install pyearth module(close)

Tags: python

**As mentioned in comments, because the module `sklearn-contrib-py-earth` was built in 2017, possibly Python version 3.9 is no longer supported this one.**

I had tried a lot of ways to install pyearth; however, they all didn't work.
So does anyone know how to solve it?

**Environment:** GCP ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, vscode version 1.64, python 3.9.10 64-bit.

```
pip3 install pyearth
```

(using sklearn-contrib-py-earth also got the same result.)

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting sklearn-contrib-py-earth
  Using cached sklearn-contrib-py-earth-0.1.0.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.16 in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.16 in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.6 in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.16->sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.16->sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.16->sklearn-contrib-py-earth) (1.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sklearn-contrib-py-earth
  Building wheel for sklearn-contrib-py-earth (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [255 lines of output]
```

`git clone` can download the fold successfully but there is still a problem for installing.

```
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth.git
cd py-earth
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-contrib-py-earth/ 
(using --cythonize option got the same result.)

```
/home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c: In function ‘__Pyx_ParseOptionalKeywords’:
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7561:21: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                     (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘PyUnicode_AsUnicode’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:45: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c:7577:25: warning: ‘_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                         (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:93,
                 from pyearth/_util.c:24:
/usr/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
 static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pyearth/_util.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
pyearth/_util.c:8071:21: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     *type = tstate->exc_type;
                     ^~~~~~~~
                     curexc_type
pyearth/_util.c:8072:22: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     *value = tstate->exc_value;
                      ^~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_value
pyearth/_util.c:8073:19: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   curexc_traceback
pyearth/_util.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
pyearth/_util.c:8080:24: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                        ^~~~~~~~
                        curexc_type
pyearth/_util.c:8081:25: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
pyearth/_util.c:8082:22: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_traceback
pyearth/_util.c:8083:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tstate->exc_type = type;
             ^~~~~~~~
             curexc_type
pyearth/_util.c:8084:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tstate->exc_value = value;
             ^~~~~~~~~
             curexc_value
pyearth/_util.c:8085:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
             curexc_traceback
pyearth/_util.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
pyearth/_util.c:8140:24: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                        ^~~~~~~~
                        curexc_type
pyearth/_util.c:8141:25: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
pyearth/_util.c:8142:22: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_traceback
pyearth/_util.c:8143:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
             ^~~~~~~~
             curexc_type
pyearth/_util.c:8144:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
             ^~~~~~~~~
             curexc_value
pyearth/_util.c:8145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
             curexc_traceback
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

And I tried `python3 -m pip install sklearn-contrib-py-earth` and `python3 -m pip install pyearth` but none of these worked.

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [255 lines of output]
      /home/jameshuang/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
...
pyearth/_util.c:8145:13: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
           tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   curexc_traceback
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sklearn-contrib-py-earth
  Running setup.py clean for sklearn-contrib-py-earth
Failed to build sklearn-contrib-py-earth
Installing collected packages: sklearn-contrib-py-earth
  Running setup.py install for sklearn-contrib-py-earth: started
  Running setup.py install for sklearn-contrib-py-earth: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for sklearn-contrib-py-earth did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [205 lines of output]
...

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> sklearn-contrib-py-earth

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Note the `/usr/lib/python2.7/` part in the traceback of the last error. You're running Python 2, not Python 3. Try using `python3` explicitly in your commands to force the use of Python 3. You do it in your second command, but not in the third one.

Comment: The first error is likely because there is no standard binary build (a wheel file) for the combination of Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.9. In fact, I don't see any wheel files listed on PyPI, so it will always need to be compiled upon installation. Which is then essentially the same as your second step: cloning and compiling yourself.

Comment: Although I note that the error message for your first attempt, which starts with `pip3 install pyearth`, shows `python setup.py bdist_wheel` at the end. So I wonder if, upon building the wheel, the installation switched from pip3/python3 to the system python. Try the first attempt once more, this time with `python3 -m pip install pyearth`.

Comment: NB: given that NumPy is installed in `$HOME/.local`, you may want to install `pyearth` there as well. In that case, don't use `sudo`, so that it automatically installs in that directory (you could use the `--user` flag to make this explicit).

Comment: Note that you show the file `pyearth/_record.c` in your second attempt, but the `pyearth` repository I can find (https://github.com/changliao1025/pyearth , linked directly from https://pypi.org/project/pyearth/ ), does *not* have this, or any other, `.c` file. What are you using?

Comment: @9769953 THX!
I tried ```git clone -b issue191 git://github.com/jcrudy/py-earth.git``` from https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth/issues/204

Comment: Note that `pyearth` (as installed with e.g. `pip3 install pyearth` and the package at `github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth.git` area absolutely *not* the same package. The latter seems to be `sklearn-contrib-py-earth` as a package to install through `pip3`, and has the last commit from December 2017; it should likely be avoided.

Comment: You show the error from `python3 -m pip install sklearn-contrib-py-earth`. But as I mention above, that package should likely be avoided; I doubt it is really what you want. Could you (also) add the error from `python3 -m pip install pyearth` instead?

Comment: @9769953 I kind of misunderstood pyearth and sklearn-contrib-py-earth at the very beginning. Then after searching documents, because all what I need is to do the MARS  algorithm, sklearn-contrib-py-earth is the correct one.

Comment: and ```python3 -m pip install pyearth``` error message is like this 
```Building wheel for gdal (setup.py) ... error  
error: subprocess-exited-with-error 
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.``` 
(it was very long so I just extracted few lines)

Comment: Actually, the long error may be the interesting one. It shows pyearth does install, and the error might be in a dependency, namely gdal. But that's hard to say without seeing the error.

Comment: Ah, ok, you want to install sklearn-contrib-py-earth. Do check, because as I mentioned, it's at least 4 years ago any change was made. And the PyPI page for it shows it to be an alpha version, with support up to Python 3.6. I also guess that the scikit-learn dependency has moved quite ahead, so any current dependencies/versions of scikit-learn may not work with it anymore.

Comment: @9769953 I think I need to find another way to finish my job. Much obliged!

Comment: @Huang James, did you solve the issue? I have the same and need to use MARS.. can't install this package

Comment: @twistfire Did either of you solve this issue?

Comment: @desert_ranger, please look here: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth/issues/221#issuecomment-1839722159
it's not simple but that worked for me.